# broken menu functions on a custom wordpress template made for me; how to fix using standard wordpress frameworks

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hello and thanks for looking. I  now suddenly in charge of a website due to Covid-19. This website is running a custom wordpress theme that was not put together well at all. The "Menu" tab was missing altogether in the admin panel so I had to figure out how to put that back together. I did. Ok. sO i am trying to create a menu with a dropdown and the standard wordpress editor is not working at all. It is visually showing it but on the actual website home page, instead of showing the child links under the parent of the dropdown, they are just all side by side. Invesitagation has shown me that there are basic dependencies in this theme missing completely for wordpress to implement the menus. Any idea on how I would reference those and bring them into this custom theme?

Comment: Can you provide us with some of the code you're working with?  It'll be next to impossible to advise you on a solution without being able to see some of the code, the errors in the console, an understanding regarding the dependencies, etc.

Comment: sure! the problem is that the console shows no errors otherwise I would be able to fix it easily. What do you want to see? The functions.php file? there isnt much in there but the basic wordpress things arent loading in the admin panel like the entire menus tab. I was able to find out how to start that but as mentioned, it just places things side by side  instead of the dropdown. I found that it is missing standard wordpress JS files but dont know which ones to start the menu dropdown

Comment: This is all just a stab in the dark, but add the theme file that places the navigation where it is, probably `header.php`, then look for `xxxxx.js` files in the theme, they may be in a sub-directory.  Can you also locate the section in the theme that has wp_enqueue_script() instructions - that way we can see what the actual scripts it's including or expecting are.  Then can you show out the generated HTML for the navigation.  If it's long, you can just truncate it to a single menu item with sub-menu.  Since there's literally no indication as to what's wrong, we'll need to check everywhere.